# Specify alias/version for AWS Event Bridge Pipe target

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I've filtered through all AWS documentation, but doesn't seem like there is support for this.. Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no way to set AWS Event Bridge pipe target to a specific alias/version? In particular step function. I want my pipe to point to a step function alias so I can maintain step function versioning, but I guess it will always point to $LATEST?

AWS console does not allow me to reference alias at all. I've tried to set target arn to qualified arn in my terraform, but that doesn't seem to work either...

Answer (score 1):

After talking to AWS support, this is not supported as of now :( There is support for versioning/aliases for Lambda target, but not step function yet. Hopefully soon...